# Delete a row in a XML column of a SQL Server table based on attribute value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, xml-column

I have a `XML` column in a SQL Server table.

The data looks like this:

```
<ColumnLayout>
    <LayoutColumns>
        <Column PropertyId="43" ColumnWidth="0" IsHidden="false" IsDefaultColumn="false" />
        <Column PropertyId="12" ColumnWidth="0" IsHidden="false" IsDefaultColumn="false" />
        <Column PropertyId="41" ColumnWidth="0" IsHidden="false" IsDefaultColumn="false" />
        <Column PropertyId="16" ColumnWidth="0" IsHidden="false" IsDefaultColumn="false" />
        <Column PropertyId="23" ColumnWidth="0" IsHidden="false" IsDefaultColumn="false" />
        <Column PropertyId="94" ColumnWidth="0" IsHidden="false" IsDefaultColumn="false" />
        <Column PropertyId="98" ColumnWidth="0" IsHidden="false" IsDefaultColumn="false" />
    </LayoutColumns>
</ColumnLayout>
```

I want to delete a column node which contains `PropertyId = 43`.

How to query that and update the XML column in that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the XQuery `.modify()` method with a `delete` command:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Content.modify('delete /ColumnLayout/LayoutColumns/Column[@PropertyId=43]')
```